# Where do I release CGMutablePathRef?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to release `CGMutablePathRef` before returning it else the application is crashes. Where should I be releasing it?

I have tried before returning but its still crashing...

```
+(UIBezierPath*) smoothedBezierOutlinePathWithCGPath:(CGPathRef)path tension:(CGFloat) tension
    {
        CGMutablePathRef smoothedCGPath = CreateSmoothedBezierPathFromPath(path, tension);
        UIBezierPath* smoothedBezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:smoothedCGPath];
        CGPathRelease(smoothedCGPath);

        return smoothedBezierPath;
    }
CGMutablePathRef CreateSmoothedBezierPathFromPath( CGPathRef path, CGFloat tention)
    {
        //convert path to 2 arrays of CGFloats
        struct dataPointer my_dataPointer; //this struct will hold the 2 indexes of the CGpath
        my_dataPointer.numberOfPoints = 0;
        my_dataPointer.isClosed = NO;
        CGPathApply(path, &my_dataPointer, savePathToArraysApplierFunc);

        //the arrays where the control points will be stored
        CGFloat controlPoints_x[2*_max_points];
        CGFloat controlPoints_y[2*_max_points];

        calculateBezierControlPoints(  controlPoints_x, controlPoints_y, my_dataPointer.indexx , my_dataPointer.indexy, my_dataPointer.isClosed, my_dataPointer.numberOfPoints, tention);

        //the final CGpath constisting of original points and computed control points
        CGMutablePathRef bezierPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        for (int i = 0; i<my_dataPointer.numberOfPoints + (int) my_dataPointer.isClosed; i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
               CGPathMoveToPoint(bezierPath, nil, my_dataPointer.indexx[0], my_dataPointer.indexy[0]);
            else if (i==my_dataPointer.numberOfPoints) //this happens when the path is closed
                CGPathAddCurveToPoint(bezierPath, nil, controlPoints_x[i*2-2], controlPoints_y[i*2-2], controlPoints_x[i*2-1], controlPoints_y[i*2-1],my_dataPointer.indexx[0], my_dataPointer.indexy[0]);
            else
                CGPathAddCurveToPoint(bezierPath, nil, controlPoints_x[i*2-2], controlPoints_y[i*2-2], controlPoints_x[i*2-1], controlPoints_y[i*2-1],my_dataPointer.indexx[i], my_dataPointer.indexy[i]);
        }
        if(my_dataPointer.isClosed)
            CGPathCloseSubpath(bezierPath);

        //app crashes here before returning.

        return bezierPath;

    }
```

Where am I suppose to release it? I have tried releasing it declaring it globally too but no use. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: By convention your method returns a retained path because it is called `Create...` so it is up to the caller of that function to release it when they are done with it

Comment: What he's saying is that the code you've posted is correct :)

Comment: What they are saying is that the caller of this method is the area where you want too look at releasing it. What calls this method? That's the right place to look at releasing when done.

Comment: sorry i have edited the code (added the method that calls it).It says SIGABRT before returning.

Comment: the app crashes when build mode/configuration is set to release.if it is in debug mode it doesn't.how do i fix it ?